# Titanium Studio cannot install Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, titanium

I have installed Android SDK before in the past, and I am trying to use the same SDK but when I use Titanium Studio to "update" it I get the error in the below screenshot. I am really unsure how to fix it when I can't even update any files listed. The same happens if I try and remove it and re-install the SDK.

Done a search on google and on here to find if anyone else has had the error with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the error message, Android SDK API 18 is not installed on your system.

However, this package isn't present in your list.

You may need to update Android SDK Tools first.